# Spliting large scm files into individual commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a very large scm file that is over 3 million lines long. I am 'cat'ing it through a telnet port to a virtual server. I need to split the code into its individual lines and feed it into the server. It should send one line and wait a few milliseconds before sending the next line. 
Ex:

```
File:

(define x (WordNode = "frustration")) \n

(define x (WordNode = "Anger")) \n
```

...

```
Input:
(define x (WordNode = "frustration")) \n

sleep 50 ms

(define x (WordNode = "Anger")) \n

sleep 50 ms
```

...

Comment: Why do you need to wait between each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `GNU` `sleep` (which supports sleeping for fractional number of seconds), it's easy:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    sleep 0.05
done < file
```

Or, turn that into a small delay-line utility (more in line with Unix philosophy).

Let's call it `delay.sh` (don't forget to `chmod +x delay.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    sleep 0.05
done
```

We are reading each line from the standard input, and output it with a delay to the standard output.

Use it, for example, like this:

```
head -100 file | ./delay.sh | ...
```

This will take the first 100 lines from `file` and feed it, one by one, with a delay to the next command in the pipeline (perhaps the `telnet` you mentioned in your question).

And to "`delay`" the complete `file`:

```
./delay.sh < file
```

Btw, if your file is `3M` lines long (as you claim), bear in mind delaying each line for `50ms` will take `~42h`.

Comment: So if I have a file ThisIsFrustrating.scm in the same dirtectory, how do I open it and have it begin reading it?

Comment: If you use it as a filter, just put in somewhere in you pipeline, `cat ThisIsFrustrating.scm | ./delay.sh | telnet .. or whatever`.

Comment: @randomir Or `./delay.sh < file | ...`.  I suggest editing before the "don't use `cat`" task force notices you ;)

Comment: @cxw, I love cats, so believe me when I tell you I'm absolutely against feline abuse. `;-)` I used `cat` only to make it clearer to the OP (but changed it to `head` now, thanks!).